# Using flatMapIterable() in RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm just starting out with RxJava and trying a sample project.

What I'm trying to achieve is

-> Get an object -> 
which contains a list of sub-objects -> Check if the sub-list satisfies a predicate condition -> and emit the sub-objects if satisfies

This is my POJO

```
public class UpComingMovies {

@SerializedName("results")
  private List<Movies> results;
}

public class Movies {

@SerializedName("overview")
  private String overview;

@SerializedName("original_language")
  private String originalLanguage;
}
```

So, from what I understand is that I can use `flatMapIterable` and transform the item to multiple observables and then use `filter` saying give me movies which has `originalLanguage.equals("en")`

This is what I have tried to do

```
 @GET("movie/upcoming")
Observable<UpComingMovies> getUpComingMovies(@Query("api_key") String apiKey, @Query("page") String page);

private final CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     disposables.add(RetrofitConnection.getService()
            .getUpComingMovies(Config.API_KEY, "1")
            .flatMapIterable(new Function<UpComingMovies, Iterable<Movies>>() {
                @Override
                public Iterable<Movies> apply(@NonNull UpComingMovies upComingMovies) throws Exception {
                    // no instance(s) of the type variable(s) U exist so that the Observable<U> conforms to a disposable
                    return upComingMovies.getResults();
                }
            })
            .filter(movies -> movies.getVoteCount() > 200).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<Movies>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(@NonNull Movies movies) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            }));
}
```

However, it does not compile. 
Cleary I do not know how to do this, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't compile is because you're returning an observable and your function signature is expecting an iterable:

```
new Function<UpComingMovies, Iterable<Movies>>() {
    @Override
    public Iterable<Movies> apply(@NonNull UpComingMovies upComingMovies) throws Exception {
        // List<Movies> is iterable
        return upComingMovies.getResults();

    }
}
```

If you fix it this way, then you can do

```
...flatMapIterable(...)
    .filter(new Predicate<Movies>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(Movies movies) throws Exception {
                return movies.originalLanguage.equals("en");
        }
    })...
```

Comment: I get an error saying - no instance(s) of the type variable(s) U exist so that the Observable<U> conforms to a disposable

Comment: `RetrofitConnection.getService()`
  `.getUpComingMovies(Config.API_KEY, "1")`
  `.flatMapIterable(UpComingMovies::getResults)`
  `.filter(movies -> movies.originalLanguage.equals("en"))`
this compiles for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is exactly what you're trying to do but replace

```
return Observable.fromIterable(upComingMovies.getResults());
```

with

```
return upComingMovies.getResults();
```

if you want your project to compile

Comment: I tried that and getting this error -  no instance(s) of the type variable(s) U exist so that the Observable<U> conforms to a disposable

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your code correctly, you get a single result of type `UpcomingMovies` (which is why you should use `Single` here and not `Observable`) and then flatten that to multiple emissions of type `Movies`. That's why your `subscribe` function doesn't work: it expects `UpcomingMovies` but gets `Movies`.

Something like this is probably what you want:

```
@GET("movie/upcoming")
Single<UpComingMovies> getUpComingMovies(@Query("api_key") String apiKey, @Query("page") String page);

RetrofitConnection.getService()
            .getUpComingMovies(Config.API_KEY, "1")
            .flatMapIterable((UpComingMovies upComingMovies) -> { 
                return upComingMovies.getResults(); 
             })
            .filter((Movies movie) -> { 
                return movie.originalLanguage.equals("en"); 
            })
            .subscribe((Movies movie) -> { 
                Log.d("", movie.toString()); 
            });
```

Comment: yes, that's what I'm doing. Since you know what I want to do, can you suggest any alternatives?